# Command line gem install error - sqlite3 - Rails New Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, sqlite, rubygems

I tried creating a new rails application in command line and had the following error. What's the problem?

I have tried working it out myself, but I'm new to coding and even reading through it I'm completely lost!

```
 /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
/Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1120:in `block in find_header'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/johnsway/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1119:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:30:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

If you need anything else, please feel free to ask!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Seems extconf.rb have problems to find headers for sqlite3. It is installed on your system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this problem has to do with a recent update of XCode. After a XCode update you need to do the following steps:

1. Open Xcode and accept the license agreement
2. Reinstall the Command Line Tools.

The second step seems to depend on your OS versions. If `xcode-select --install` does not work try to start the `Install Command Line Developer Tools` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

After reinstalling the Command Line Tools try to rerun `bundle install`.

Comment: You were spot on! I ran XCode and it installed the updates and asked me to agree to the new T&Cs. I did not need to complete step 2 since the console returned that they were already installed. My new rails command worked fine. Thanks!